# Integrating RelayJS and Azure table storage

Tags: relayjs, relay

The [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/getting-started.html#content) on RelayJS says the RelayJS can use node.js as a GraphQL server, but not ASP.NET web service.

How can I use RelayJS with ASP.NET web api end point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How can I use RelayJS with ASP.NET web api end point?**

TL;DR;

By placing a GraphQL server in-between Relay client-side and ASP.NET web api end point.

---

The [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/getting-started.html) page of Relay documentation clearly mentions that 2 additional things are needed to use Relay:

1. A GraphQL Schema: This is your data model. You need to map your ASP.NET web API to a GraphQL schema.
2. A GraphQL Server: Your client-side speaks to this server. In your case, this GraphQL server will talk to your ASP.NET web API.

A good example of this is [GraphQL schema and server wrapping Star Wars API](https://github.com/graphql/swapi-graphql).

---

**Some conecptual clarifications about your question**

1. Relay is a specification. It's actually called [GraphQL Relay Specification](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-relay-specification.html#content). It's not restricted to JavaScript. Check [Awesome Relay](https://github.com/expede/awesome-relay) to find the list of languages for which Relay libraries are already available.
2. It helps to think of Relay and GraphQL as 2 sides:

   - server-side consisting of GraphQL server, which speaks the schema. It can receive queries and mutation requests. How you prepare and provide the requested data depend on back-end logic. For example, you may have your own database, which you use directly to fetch / prepare the exposed data. Or you may use an external API to fetch / prepare data.
     There are libraries in languages other than JavaScript to help you write GraphQL schema and server. Check [Awesome GraphQL](https://github.com/chentsulin/awesome-graphql).
   - client-side using Relay library, which talks to a GraphQL server and fetches data as needed.